# Reading and writing keycloak secrets to hashicorp vault using vault spi

Tags: keycloak, hashicorp-vault

I am using jboss/keycloak docker image (uses wildfly as app server) and we are leveraging keycloak as an identity broker and user federation. I want to store the keycloak specific secrets in hashicorp vault, and basically access these secrets at runtime.

The identity service is written in java where I have created a customized vault (hashicorp) provider using the vault spi. I have used [this](https://github.com/micedre/keycloak-hashicorp-vault-ext) extension to add the vault provider.The provider is integrated now, and I am able to see it in the provider list. Wanted to check how can I store and retrieve keycloak secrets (like realm ids, ldap credentials, external tokens etc) from this vault.